# synchronise local directories over ssh

Tags: unix, ssh, local-storage, synchronization

The following command works great for me for a single file:

```
scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory
```

What I want to do is do it recursive (i.e. for all subdirectories / subfiles of a given path on server), merge folders and overwrite files that already exist locally, and finally downland only those files on server that are smaller than a certain value (e.g. 10 mb).

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rsync.

Your command is likely to look like this:

```
rsync -az --max-size=10m your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory
```

`-a` (archive mode - the sync is recursive, transfers ownership, attributes, symlinks among other things)
`-z` (compresses transfer)

`--max-size` (only copies files up to a certain size)

There are many more flags which may be suitable. Checkout the docs for more details - http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Answer (score 0):

First option: use `rsync`.

Second option, and it's not going to be a one liner, but can be done in three or four lines:

Create a tar archive on the remote system using `ssh`.
Copy the tar from remote system with `scp`.
Untar the archive locally.

If the creation of the archive gets a bit complicated and involves using `find` and/or `tar` with several options it is quite practical to create a script which would do that locally, upload it on the server with `scp`, and only then execute remotely with `ssh`.

Comment: that's not a bad option indeed but it doesn't take into account the fact that I want to get rid of the big files. any ideas?

Comment: To tar files in current directory smaller than 4k (you can put it in a file, transfer to the remote host and execute there using ssh): `tar cf a.tar ${find . -type f -size -4096c}`